# ETC/ETH split still safe after October 18 2016 hardfork?

Tags: ether, ethereum-classic, replay-attack

Does this Steemit solution still work in exactly the same manner as before the HF of October 18th? Do I need to wait for the second HF/ETC HF coming next week, or can I try splitting already (since the etc price is dropping)?

https://steemit.com/ethereum/@pauls/ethereum-fork-step-by-step-guide-to-safely-splitting-your-eth-etc

One more question: is it safe to use my etc deposit address on poloniex as my etc recipient address for the split contract? This way i don't have to create a pre(dao)fork etc wallet in mist

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Test with small amounts first.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the code of that contract could have been affected by the hard fork. It should work in the same way as it did 1 week ago.
About the tutorial, I would suggest you to use a more updated version of Mist (the latest one)

You can use the ETC address of Poloniex.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I already installed the newest wallet though I still have problems synching (hope the second HF fixes this problem completely). I wondered because i wasn't sure if the hf would create new replay risks/coins (etc classic/neo or eth/eth after hf) that would create problems for the splitting contract.

Comment: Currently there are no more recognized altcoins created after this hardfork and they shouldn't be in the future either (I hope Poloniex doesn't list them...).